# Is there any way to answer a call or originate a call by Kamailio?

Tags: kamailio

I know that Kamailio works as a SIP Proxy and I also know that Asterisk/FreeSWITCH or other similar products can do what I'm asking here, but still wondering if it's possible to use Kamailio to answer a call or originate a call?

Let's say, "User ---> Kamailio", Kamailio answer the call with "200 OK to INVITE", and then play an announcement "Thank you for using Kamailio", then BYE the call?

I can't find any related information so I guess the answer is no, but still want to double check.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can answer and play message if you use kamailio with mediaproxy.

Mediaproxy docs have some samples.

Originate is problematic and unreasonable in most cases, but there is https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/rtimer.html

Much simple method is use SIPP or perl/python sip module(external), after that rewrite call in kamailio as you wish.